# Extending the standard swift library

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to extend the standard library in swift? Or to expand a framework?

I would like to have something like this:

```
extension {
    func printLog (message: String) {

    }
}
```

or

```
extension UIKit {
    func printLog (message: String) {

    }
}
```

I would like to call a function from everywhere without importing something

Kind regards
Alex

Comment: have you tried simply defining a `func printLog` outside of any class, simply put it under the imports in a swift file?

Comment: yes, it's possible. You can extend any class and use it later

Comment: @iamalizade but he is not asking about a class but a Module, in particular the `Swift` Module.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as provided by @[luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302), is very simple. Just define a function outside of any class.

Example:

```
import Foundation

func printLog (message: String) {
    //Do something
}

class MyClass { ...
```